# Why does it take 9 months to access the Orion service module interconnect?

Tags: orion-spacecraft

In [this story](https://www.theverge.com/2020/11/30/21726753/nasa-orion-crew-capsule-power-unit-failure-artemis-i) (versions of which are in several other places) it is reported that it could take nine months to access and replace a Power Data Unit on the Orion spacecraft, one component of which has failed?

> Replacing the PDU isn’t easy. The component is difficult to reach: it’s located inside an adapter that connects Orion to its service module — a cylindrical trunk that provides support, propulsion, and power for the capsule during its trip through space. To get to the PDU, Lockheed Martin could remove the Orion crew capsule from its service module, but it’s a lengthy process that could take up to a year. As many as nine months would be needed to take the vehicle apart and put it back together again, in addition to three months for subsequent testing, according to the presentation

So my question is why? What takes that long? I'm not looking for political answers, I'm interested in the technical constraints that make a critical path that long.

Comment: I suppose because of safety protocols. If you screw a nut in a spacecraft you should check all the documentation to be sure all is done right, and probably should re-test the system for spaceflight readiness. The Russian Nauka module for ISS is a good (bad) example. The launch was postponed for many years because of impurities in propulsion system. It was found very hard to clear without complete rebuild of the whole module. So the manufacturers finally gave up and stated the risks are "acceptable" without cleaning.